# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I want to use a flutter package 'audioplayers' but when I run my code I have this error

```
C:\Users\Utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\xylophone_flutter\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\Utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\xylophone_flutter\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\Utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\xylophone_flutter\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

And when I change `minSdkVersion 16` to 23 on `myApp/android/app/build.gradle`, I have another error

```
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (181, 52): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (231, 38): Expecting an argument
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\ByteDataSource.kt: (8, 37): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedMediaPlayer.kt: (10, 39): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (168, 32): Expecting a parameter declaration
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (205, 26): Expecting an argument
e: C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\WrappedSoundPool.kt: (46, 77): Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is List<???> but MutableList<WrappedSoundPool> was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

How to solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/720

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to edit the `build.gradle` file located inside your project directory like `your_project_folder\android\app\build.gradle` and find and edit this line `minSdkVersion 16` to `minSdkVersion 23` then save the file use `flutter clean` command and **run** it.

The **defaultConfig** should look like this inside the **build.gradle** file

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.your_package_name_here"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Hope the above solution will work.

Or better use the old version of audioplayers.
Edit in your **pubspec.yaml** file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  audioplayers: ^0.10.0
```

Comment: Use this version.. audioplayers: ^0.10.0

Comment: worked for react-native as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, changing the SDK version in the build.gradle didn't solve the problem.
I simply downgraded to audioplayers: 0.17.0, make sure to remove the ^ before the 0. It should work for you

Comment: Didid't solved the problem that either in mi case/ It says: Because audioplayers >=0.16.2 <0.18.0 depends on uuid ^2.2.2 and feeddy_flutter depends on uuid ^3.0.4, audioplayers >=0.16.2 <0.18.0 is forbidden.
So, because feeddy_flutter depends on audioplayers 0.17.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in feeddy_flutter...                          
pub get failed (1; So, because feeddy_flutter depends on audioplayers 0.17.0, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

I added the lines without realizing that it was already there in gradle.build so I ended up with:

```
  minSdkVersion 23
  targetSdkVersion 30
  minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
  targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

so these two properties are probably replaced with NULL or something.

Solution: At the root of the project you have a local.properties file, add:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=23
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
```

Also keep the gradle.build file as it was originally:

```
  minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
  targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

and add below

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
```

the following:

```
def minSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')

def targetSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion')
```